# export mysql same value multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql

I am exporting data from a database, and need to export the same value to multiple columns/records.

Right now I have it going to

```
value as base_image,
```

Is there a way to split that to multiple exports?

Such as

```
value as base_image + small_image + thumbnail_image,
```

So that it splits into multiple columns on the csv export?

Id rather do this then run the same cherry picking code again and again for two more columns.

Magento2 import sucks and requires these values to each be set to fully import the product and resize the images correctly for display.

I don't really know how to word this better or even search for it, it appears to be one of those "one off's" for me so sorry in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hesitate to post this because it's so simple, so don't take offense if I have misunderstood what you are asking for, but writing the "same value to multiple columns" would look like this:

```
select value as base_image, value as small_image, value as thumbnail_image
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I was hoping to just add it over and over with the same logic but I was over thinking it. I ended up having to run the logic again and again to different columns. I guess your answer made me just do it that way :)